# Is it possible to do bad deeds without sense of doership?

Tags: karma, yoga

So I think I get more or less the importance of doing good deeds without attaching sense of doership - you don't accumulate karma, ego is controlled etc.

But what about bad deeds. What do scriptures say if I do a bad deed without doership? Or is that not even possible?

Will be most helpful if someone can point out examples of such deeds in scriptures. Or specify where in scriptures it says such deeds are not possible

Comment: Generally, those who are without the sense of doership are supposed to be spiritually advanced, so they dont do things contrary to dharma. That said, some one under the influence of drugs might be able to do bad things without a sense of doership.

Comment: We're complicating things too much. Every deed is done with sense of doership. Without that it's not possible to do anything. It's like trying to 'speak before thinking' - literally impossible because thought comes first. Anyways, there are different results for the same action. And you can aspire to any of those results. Depending on what you desire, your spiritual level is high or down. e.g. if you give money to a beggar, you'll get punya. if you kick a beggar, you'll get papa. Think of it as credit and debit. Both of them WILL be enforced by Bhagavan...

Comment: After they are enforced, you can again get punya or papa. And the results of THOSE will again be enforced. So on, endlessly, birth after birth, death after death. So far so good? Now, the question comes, hmm.. i'm bored of this repetition. What if I want to stop it and get out of the cycle ? Well, it's very simple - stop accumulating punya & papa. Stop donating and stop kicking. Great, can I get out of the cycle ? Not so fast.. because your previous donation and previous kicks are still in balance. Until they are enforced, you can't leave. Oh.. so I gotta wait until my balance is zero? Yep.

Comment: Alright, how long with the clearance take ? Depends on how much balance you have. Well, it might be really large. Yes, it might. So, what am i supposed to do until it gets cleared. Well.. nothing. If you do any good or bad deed, you're going to add to your balance and extend your stay. Ohh.. I don't wanna do that. Well, you don't have a choice. Really, no choice ? Well, actually, there is a little secret. Great, what is it ? Alright, remember how all this time, you donated and enjoyed its results, and kicked and suffered the results. What if I told you, you do either and not face consequences?

Comment: Wow.. is that possible? Won't Bhagavan enforce all punya & papa ?If a man doesn't get salary for his work, or thief doesn't get punished for his crime, the world will collapse in 2 days, right? True, it will. But that's not what Bhagavan is gonna do. He is going to continue to enforce them, whether you want them or not.. But, But.. Hang on, we're close. Remember how after your first donation and your first kicking, you got your first reward and your first punishment ? End of story right ? Now, stop and think. What made you donate and kick the SECOND time ? and you got THOSE results.

Comment: Then, what made you do them a 3rd time ?.. and 100th ? and trillionth? That's where the secret lies. It's called vasana, or ruchi, or impressions. Even if you bank balance goes to zero, there is a unmarked account in a different ledger, which stores the mental impressions of these punya & papa consequences. Until THAT secret book is cleared to zero, you can't escape from the main cycle. Holy crap, why wasn't I told about this book before. Well, because you didn't get bored until now and you didn't ask for it until now. Wow, this is like a lost treasure map. Now, how do i clear THAT balance?

Comment: Let's take a step back for a second. It's clear that you have some punya & papa karma balance remaining in your account. Until that's cleared, you can't leave. Even if it is cleared, you can't leave until your vasana account is cleared. Clearing the karma balance is simple - Don't do any new karma, and wait until previous ones are exhausted. But not doing new karma is impossible, as long as you're alive, even if you breathe, you're doing good to myself but harm to bacteria. Or ants get crushed when you walk. Or insects get burnt when you cook food etc.

Comment: Until we're dead, it's not possible to stop doing punya/papa. So, there are 2 roadblocks to getting out of the cycle - Avoid doing new karma, AND get rid of vasana account. What an excellent problem to have.. and Bhagavan, being the genius that he is, has given a solution. For Both. SIMULTANEOUSLY. Want to know what it is ?

Comment: Karma Yoga. Go ahead, do karma. But only the karma that Bhagavan has sanctioned. Even actively avoiding karma that Bhagavan has forbidden is a type of mental karma that you're dong, so that's good too. So, you're free to do all the works recommended down in scriptures, and you're free to avoid all the works forbidden by scriptures. But, But.. am I not adding to my karma balance ? Well, do it with one thought. This thought will make or break your goal. Earlier, anytime you donated or kicked, you did it with a different thought - the thought of enjoying the results.

Comment: Now, do it WITHOUT the thought of enjoying. That's the SECRET. Anytime you mentally enjoy or fantasize about the results of your actions, your VASANA balance is increased. So, all this time, even after the actual consequences of your actions got exhausted by Bhagavan from his account books, you are maintaining a separate account book where your Vasanas just keep on increasing, with no sign of decreasing. Until now, when you learn this secret. Do all those actions, WITHOUT the desire of enjoying the results. But.. why would i work if I don't desire salary, or donate if I don't desire punya?

Comment: Have you forgotten already ? Remember how you said you were bored/tired of this endless cycle ? That you wanted to get out? That you still had karma balance ? That you had to live until karma balance was zero? That you still had vasana balance ? In the time you have remaining until your karma balance is zeroed out, do karma (given in scriptures), but FORGET about its results. Remember, you're only doing them to pass time. You have no interest in enjoying the results. Do it like a machine, which does things exactly as programmed, but doesn't care about results. This is actual freedom.

Comment: Keep on doing it, until Bhagavan has exhausted all your karma punya papa balance by creating situations which cause you happiness and sadness. Keep on doing it, until you have lost all vasanas in the results of your karma. Then you become free.

Comment: Now, lets' get back to your question. Can i do sin without sense of doership? This whole idea of 'sense of doership' or the lack of it, is only for people who care about samsara, getting out of it, being spiritually inclined, reading Gita, right ? So, when Gita says 'Do karma that is given in shastras. Forget about its results. Keep only the bigger result of FREEDOM in mind' - It is very clear - Simply do what shastras say. Does shastra say kick a beggar? Kick him. Does shastra say donate to a beggar? Donate to him.

Comment: Take your brain out of the equation. And remember, by definition, whatever Bhagavan has recommended is Punya. Whatever he has not is Papa. Not the other way round, where people question whether what Bhagavan said or did is Punya/Papa. We people are useless mortals. Our questioning or judgement of what is right or wrong, is mostly childish and short sighted. Bhagavan has given a manual. Simply follow it. And obtain your result.

Comment: Yes it is possible you can for example kill ants or other insects without knowing this.

Comment: Yes bad deed too done by god only for you.. you are not the doer of your action.. but the taught and desire is generated by you so the effect is for you only.  in effect papa comes the attached to bad deed automatically for the jiva. as jiva is the primary cause of the bad deed.. even tough jiva is well aware of God is the doer.. surgery is done for the diseased person to get cured the effect of surger is going to patient not the doctor.

Comment: if somebody works for you the effect of profit or loss from the work goes to the owner but actually worker is doing.. he has no loss.. because he is doing his work

Comment: @ram This is not the purpose of comments

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you define bad deeds. If bad deed is done knowingly in your eyes that it is bad it might have a bad intention. And you get paap.
 When you do not have doership you simply do not see deeds as good or evil or bad. They are just deeds then. Your kartavya( if the situations actually demand that karma and to know that you need to be unbiased and see clearly from all P.O.V.s). In that case you do not accumulate karma.
In the latter case your karma might be perceived as bad but you do not get paap.
But you have to be very cautious no doership or nishkaam karma can only come to you if you understand the concept very deeply and are truly unbiased and able to see clearly.

Comment: So you are saying it is possible to do bad deeds without sense of ownership? When you say situations demand kartavya - then by default it means I have to do karma as per Dharma which means I can only do good deeds @sangita saxena

Comment: @Carmensandiego I think Sangita is saying that good & bad are illusory so the question only makes sense when participating in this illusion

Comment: @Carmen sandiego No, this does not mean you can only do good deeds. No doership and nishkaam karma will make you go into practicing karma yoga where your karma will not remain good or bad or evil karma, they will become karma and this karma will not give you any paap or punya. Try discovering what nishkaam karma is regularly until you truly discover it. Start by searching the term on various sites.

Comment: @Carmen sandiego Being mindful is very important to achieve no doership. Vipassana can be a good start.

Comment: @Sangita Saxena - Yes, I understand Nishkama karma. So my question is can any act under Nishkama karma be considered bad in the eyes of others. An example would help

Comment: @Carmen sandiego Yes, in a TV show Shani deva was shown breaking the legs of a man who lied to his children that he can't walk so that his children do all the hard work while he does nothing. Shani deva did this to him to spare him from losing his respect from his children.

Comment: Remember half knowledge is more dangerous than a lie. Plus this life is like a theatre we should do our best acting, our deeds within should always carry a good intention.

Comment: @SangitaSaxena - The tv series example seems to be of an example of a person committing a sin (i.e. lie in this case). I am looking for example where act is considered bad in eyes of others and yet i am not punished for it.

Comment: Shani deva's act could be considered bad by someone, still he won't get punished for it.

Comment: @SangitaSaxena - Why will Shani deva's act be considered bad ? He is performing his duties of punishing the sinner